# Updated version number not showing

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, ota-update, android-versions, system-info

I just installed an upgrade (to `22.46.12`) on my 2nd gen Moto G LTE, that said it upgraded to Android 5.1. Before the upgrade I was on 5.0.2 and system version `22.41.24`, and now I am on `22.46.12`, but Android version in settings still shows I am on 5.0.2. In addition, when I check for software updates through settings it tells me my phone is up to date
Has the update applied, or only in part (in addition to the Android OS update it fixed the StageFright vulnerability), or not at all and the system version number is wrongly updated?

**Edit:** after a while on Motorola's waiting list, I received a message saying:

> We would like to confirm that your phone now supports the latest software version available for it

However checking for software updates still returns the "your devices software is up-to-date" message

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*that said it upgraded to Android 5.1*" -- how do you know that?

Comment: "Highlights of this update include: Android 5.1 lollipop, a sweet new take on Android..."

Comment: I got the above behaviour on a 2nd gen Moto G 4G but on a 1st gen Moto G an update that appeared to have the same wording did update the version number to 5.1 and the system version to 221.21.56.

Comment: The 1st gen updates were prioritised and came out first,  possibly any bugs in the update were fixed earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem on my Moto G 2nd Gen 4G where after the update my Android version stayed on 5.0.2 and did not change to 5.1 like I expected. I contacted Motorola about the issue and they confirmed that Android 5.0.2 Lollipop is currently the latest version of Android for the Moto G 2nd Gen. They couldn't however explain why I had received a false OTA update and promised to raise the issue. So from what I can tell, the OTA update is most likely to be an error on Motorola's behalf but this should be fixed when Android 6.0 Marshmallow is released for the 2nd Gen Moto G.

Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: That's exactly my situation (but with a less helpful response from Motorola in my case). Is the 6.0 update definitely coming out for the 2nd gen LTE, given that the 3rd gen is already out?